# How to pass asynchronous data to child component? Angular

Tags: angular, observable, parent-child, parent

I have a **Parent Component** where I make a http request, get Observable in return and subscribe to it :

```
this.bookingService.getBooking().subscribe((r) => {
  this.booking = r['result'];
});
```

I pass the *booking* variable to **Child Component** like this:

```
<child *ngIf="booking" [booking]="booking"></child>
```

In my child component I receive that variable and I use ngOnChanges to listen to changes on that variable. I need to use this variable immediately as the child component is loaded.

```
@Input() booking: Booking;
```

.
.
.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
if (changes['booking']) {
  this.createForm(this.booking.reference);
}}
```

I believe that that before the request is finished in **Parent Component** the *booking* variable is passed to child as undefined.

---

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ **EDIT** @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

**Child component** is a modal popup.
In the **Parent component** I have a button that shows that modal(component) and after clicking that button, `ngOnInit` fires up in **Child component** , however `ngOnChanges` does not...

**Parent-component.ts:**

`openUpdateReservationPopup() { this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(UpdateReservationComponent, { class: 'modal-dialog-centered' }); }`

**Parent-component.html:**

`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="openUpdateReservationPopup()" *ngIf="showButton()"> <span class="booking-content-actions-label">Open popup</span> </button>`

@@@@@@@@@@@@@ **END OF EDIT** @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

---

Nothing works so far. I have tried separating in the **Parent Component** the Observable and passing it to the child component (with async pipe and without it), and then subscribing ( inside ngOnInit() ) to that observable in the **Child Component**.

**Parent-component.ts**

```
this.bookingObservable$ = this.bookingService.getBooking();
this.bookingObservable$.subscribe((r) => {
  this.booking = r['result'];
});
```

**Parent-component.html**

```
<child *ngIf="booking" [bookingObservable$]="bookingObservable$ | async"></child>
```

as well as:

```
<child *ngIf="booking" [bookingObservable]="bookingObservable$ "></child>
```

**Child-component.ts**

```
@Input() bookingObservable$: any;

ngOnInit() {
this.bookingObservable$.subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val);
  this.createReferenceNumberForm(val.reference);
});
```

}

Comment: Could you create this on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: It would be better if you try to use the behavior subject.

Comment: Why don't you use `@Input() public set booking(value: Booking) { /* do something */ }`. You're just making it too complicated

Comment: Even if I not use ngOninit or ngOnChanges, and I type console.log("inside set") inside /*do smth*/ it doesn't display the message, it's not getting there

Comment: Please take a look at the EDIT in the question - the child component is a modal activated on click from the parent

Answer (score 3):

You only need this code in the parent :

```
<child *ngIf="booking" [booking]="booking"></child>
```

but in the child, change your your condition in ngOnChanges :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
 if (changes['booking']?.currentValue) {
 this.booking=changes['booking'].currentValue;
 this.createForm(this.booking.reference);
}}
```

Comment: When I add `console.log("test")` before `if (changes['booking']?.currentValue)` it doesn't display *test* in console at all

Comment: Please take a look at the EDIT in the question - the child component is a modal activated on click from the parent

Comment: Ah, in this case you need to pass the input in the ts class of your parent (not in the template) , like this : this.modalRef.componentInstance.booking=this.booking